# Wordpress PHP Syntax

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a PHP 'if' statement that tells an image to display on certain pages in Wordpress. What I'm trying to do is shown below, but I think the syntax is incorrect.

I'm trying to say "If the page displayed equals 'about' or 'gallery' and that page is not 'services', go ahead and display the image.

Here's the section of code that you should be able to analyze and see where I went wrong:

```
<?php if(is_page('about' || 'gallery') && (is_page != 'services')) { ?>
 <li><img id="profile_pic" alt="DermaKare (Official Fan Page)" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/50556_123510051042639_3343345_n.jpg" class="photo img" /></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Banner") ) : ?>
        <?php /*?><p><a href='<?php bloginfo('siteurl')?>/wp-admin/widgets.php'>Widgetize this sidebar</a></p><?php */?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.....

Comment: I think it's just the first half of the code that needs to be looked at, not the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( ( is_page('about') || is_page('gallery') ) && !is_page('services') )
```

watch the brackets.

**edit:** and what @hakre said, if it's about or gallery, it never is services

Answer (score 3):

If a page is `about` or `gallery` then it never is `services`. So you can spare that not part.

Next to that you need to call the function twice:

```
if (is_page('about') || is_page('gallery'))
{
    # then
}
```

This should do it. Wrapped into your code this should look like:

```
<?php if  (is_page('about') || is_page('gallery')) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( (is_page('about') || is_page('gallery') ) && (!is_page('services') ) {
 echo "<li><img id=\"profile_pic\" alt=\"DermaKare (Official Fan Page)\" src=\"http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/50556_123510051042639_3343345_n.jpg\" class=\"photo img\" /></li>";
} ?>
```

this should work

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried it and it didn't work for some reason.  I know your code makes sense, and I double checked how I'm identifying the page and it seems correct.  Any other ideas?  I could let you login if you want to look yourself.....let me know

Comment: @RobMyrick It seems I forgot to close `(!is_page('services') )`. It should be `(!is_page('services') ) )`. Try it now

Comment: Mike I used your code intertwined with an answer below.  thanks for your help